# in spring batch, setting job parameters in job execution listener before Job execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new spring batch.
     I am running the Job using CommandLineRunner. I have some properties in .properties file.
    for ex:

```
 my.path=mydir_{event1}_{event2}
```

So the event1 and event2 this strings need to get replace with the runtime job parameters. As I am running Job using commandLine runner,
I added JobExecutionListener to the Job and tried to write code in beforeJob 
but I am not able to set the parameters from the beforeJob funciton
Can anybody help me on this requirement.
I want something like this.

```
@Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    String event1= jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("event1");
   String filepath=replace("{event1}", event1);

  jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("filepath",filepath);
}
```

.jobExecution.getExecutionContext() this doesn't work. Is there any other way to do this thing.
It does not work means->
after putting value inside the executioncontext. I use the the key inside spring-job-context.xml using
 `#{jobExecutionContext['filepath']}`
So by using this way, I am not able to get the value which I have set in beforeJob function.

Comment: that is the right approach. When you say `jobExecution.getExecutionContext()` doesn't work, what do you mean ? Do you get any error? If so what is it?

Comment: Do you pass event1 and event2 parameters through command line?

Comment: @CorkKochi yes I pass those parameters from commandline

Comment: Do u get those parameters in main method

Comment: i get those parameters in beforeJob() method. I am not using Main class to run this job.

Comment: So you are getting those values in beforeJob method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144447/discussion-between-cork-kochi-and-kamini).

Comment: I dot understand what is not working ... but you can use a job listener if your problem persists.

Comment: @Kamini, as others have mentioned, this is a valid way to add something to the job execution context. What happens when you later try to get the `filepath` out of the execution context? Do you just get `null`? Does the `ApplicationContext` fail to be created? Do you have any logging?

Comment: @kamini did you ever solve this? I'm also trying to set some properties in the `beforeJob` but doesn't seem to be persisted

Comment: @Kamini, if this is resolved, can you please let me know what needs to be done, even if I have a similar requirement?